# Start flash on HTML load

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3

I have a flash musicplayer, that is very simple by itself. it has one button, Start/Stop.
The player itself is in footer.

The Problem: when the page loads music won't start (FLASH player won't play) before you don't see it on the page, I mean, when the screen is small by resolution, you don't see the footer - and music doesn't start. when you scroll down to footer (when you see the player) it starts playing.

How should I do that no matter if you see the player or not - the player starts playing.

THANKSSS!!!!

Comment: Just keeping it simple, can you design your site so that the player is at the top of the page?

Comment: no i can't... i haven't designed the site... I'm against of the music in the background

Comment: bloody right to be against it: please get that designer fired

Answer (score 1):

Do play & stop buttons in JavaScript for the 1px square player in position fixed on the top.

in javascript :

```
str = "stop";

function appel(str) {
    document.getElementById("id_flash").echo(str);
}
```

in as3 :

```
import flash.external.*;

function echo(str:String):Void {
    switch(str) {
        case "play":
            sound.play();
            break;
        case "stop":
            sound.stop();
            break;
    }
}

ExternalInterface.addCallback("echo", null, echo);
```

Comment: What does the sound(str); bit do?